# Delete selected row column in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Can I delete the first column of a DataGridView?

[image]

Comment: Before or after you have loaded the data? And are you using Data Binding? Would hiding it be OK?

Comment: try this `dataGridView1.Columns["FirstColumn"].Visibility = false;`

Comment: To hide the row headers you can use the property RowHeadersVisible and set it to false.

To make the row headers smaller you can use the property RowHeadersWidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide first column you can set RowHeadersVisible to false of your dataGrid

```
dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible=false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can hide that column

```
gvGridViewID.Columns[0].Visible = false;
```

Do this after you have `gvGridViewID.DataBind();`

But if the column is not required at all then you need to remove it from your datasource itself, before providing it as datasource to the gridview.

***Note***: Where `gvGridViewID`(you might be having some other name) is the ID of the grid.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions

1. The first one is to delete the column from the Data Source. This one is before assigning the data source.
2. The second one is by hiding the column from the grid i.e.

   ```
   yourGridViewName.Columns["yourColumnName"].Visibile = false;

   yourGridViewName.Columns[ColumnNo].Visibile = false;
   ```

This solution is after assigning the datasource